# event.request.destination = unknown for a html page being cached by service worker

Tags: javascript, html, service-worker

On my webpage, I am trying to come up with a strategy to not cache HTML pages but cache all the rest. I tried to use `event.request.url` to distinguish between HTML pages and other links but wasn't able to find an efficient way to do it.

So, I thought of using `event.request.destination`. As far as I could understand, `event.request.destination` gives a way for determining the type of a request by storing a kind of string keyword. For example, for CSS pages, it stores style.

For this HTML page it gives that `event.request.destination = "unknown"`. However, no list of values I found for `event.request.destination` have **unknown** in them.
Can anybody tell me what is the reason that `event.request.destination = "unknown"` or is it just like when `event.request.destination = ""`?

[List of values for event.request.destination](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RequestDestination)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `event.request.mode`, this value will be equal to `navigate` when it load a webpage https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/mode

Comment: That might work. I was initially using `event.request.destination === "document"` as a check for HTML pages, however, HTML pages were getting cached. On further inspection, I found out that it was giving `event.request.destination = "unknown"`. I still don't know what it means.
I will give your answer a shot though. Will update if I find anything.